# Windows 10 1709 (Fall Creators) Update Epson Stylus Color 880 Driver Not Working

Tags: windows-10, printer, epson-stylus

We just updated an older system to **Win10 1709** (we had to remove the wifi card to get it to install).

This works well, however, for the life of my I don't know what's happened to our **Epson Stylus Color 880** printer. This *used* to work well for the past 7+ years, but now it is not supported on the system for some reason.

- Whenever we plug the printer in (we have tried uninstalling it), it
  basically shows up as "USB Printer" in the Devices/Printers page.
- In Device Manager, it shows as "Epson Stylus Color 880" (like it
  should).
- If I try updating the driver, and even do the "manual selection" method - choosing Epson Stylus Color 880, it says "Downloading Driver" and then "Installing Driver" to which it says there is an error and cannot continue.
- If I remove the printer and re-install, the same problem occurs

Do you have any ideas as to what I could do to fix the problem? I know the printer is supported on Win10 because another Win10 laptop we have prints fine with it.

Many thanks.

--

Update

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Epson site to see if they have an up-to-date driver?

Comment: @AFH Funny, I just did it and they say that "Windows 10 S printer drivers will automatically install for compatible Epson models when you plug your printer into your Windows 10 S device". Drivers for Epson Stylus Color 880 at the website are for Win7 or older.

Comment: Does the error message has a code?

Comment: No error codes, although we've now added another printer (HP C7200) and the exact same problem has happened. I will add images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this in the end...

---

By deleting the following folder, it all resolved:

```
c:/Windows/spool/drivers/x64/3
```

Deleted that, removed the printers from "Print Management" and then restarted. Printers added automatically and had the correct names etc.